# Making CSS code segment compatible with multiple browsers?

Tags: html, css, image, cross-browser

I have about a weeks worth of CSS/HTML experience and have been stumped on this issue for about half an hour now. I really do not know how to adapt this code segment in order for it to run successfully on different browsers. It works fine on Chrome, aligning the pictures in a row of four, evenly spaced, but does not work for Safari. I have not tested whether or not it works on Firefox. If someone could show me how to adapt this code, I would appreciate it greatly.

```css
#containermain {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#containermain div {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
#containermaintext div {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
#containermain div:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
#containermain div:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="containermain" class="slideExpandUp">
  <div>
    <a href="physics.html">
      <img src="images/atom.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="math.html">
      <img src="images/mathematics.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="humanities.html">
      <img src="images/books.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="stem.html">
      <img src="images/stem.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari are you testing on? If 6.1 or below, I recommend `-webkit-` before the `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.

Comment: Check this to see the browser support: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp . Older browsers need vendor specific tags, like -moz- for firefox, -webkit- for safari, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a PC and don't have safari to check it, but I recommend adding in-line block to the inside divs like this:

```
        #containermain div {
             /*width: 250px;*/
             width: 20%;
             display:inline-block;
             height: auto;
             background: rgb(255,255,255,0);
         }
```

I also changed the width so that it will scale responsively and not break into another row.